# MVC website hosted in IIS using .net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have uploaded a .net mvc site to the production server however whenever I now try to login I just get...

"Invalid login attempt"

This worked perfectly in dev environment and the db has been uploaded as it was. I wonder if something is not right with .net identity but all my settings are the same as in dev.

Any Ideas?

*Update*

Actually think my login mechanism was hiding the real issue, I'm using ef and whenever the website tries to connect to the db I get...

DataException->EntityException->SqlException:
Cannot attach the file ‘{0}' as database '{1}'

Full Error

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach the file 'D:\Websites\CMT\App_Data\Default.mdf' as database 'Default'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +356
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +132
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +246
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +238
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +319
```

Comment: Just looking at a successful ef website I have had in the past and it did not have any .mdf file in the app_data folder but the website in question above does

Comment: This is my webconfig for ef connection factory

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, `EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>`

Comment: Please submit connection strings segments of the web config file.

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Is the connection string contains `AttachDbFilename`? if so remove it and let SQL server creates DB file in its defaults location.

Comment: It does not contain AttachDbFilename

Comment: Could you please submit the `DbContext` then?

Comment: Have you using LocalDB for local connection to SQL Server instance? If the MDF file attached to a remote server in production environment and defined in connection string, remove LocalDB data provider section from your project via Server Explorer or editing web.config manually.